# AnyLogic - Cars do not stop at traffic light's lane connector

Tags: anylogic

Any experiences or ideas why cars do not stop at a traffic light that is defined by lane connectors, but do when the traffic light is defined by stop lines? This phenomena is valid for all 15 traffic lights in my model and there is no manipulation of the car-agent. Please find an exemplary intersection [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEl78.png)

Update: The [get-methods](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2Fmarkup%2FRoadLanesConnector.html) indicate that the lane connectors are connected correctly to the related road and lane, respectively.

Update2: I can reproduce the phenomena in an example model from AnyLogic ("Traffic Light Phases Optimization"). With standard scale, the traffic lights work flawlessly; with the scale of my model (43 px for 505 meter ruler), the cars do not stop at traffic lights. Can we call that a bug?

Comment: i just made the simplest possible example and cars stop perfectly fine

Comment: Hi Felipe, which scale do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct with the scale question. In fact the road traffic library works horribly when you don't use the preferred scale, which is 4 pixels per meter. If you deviate too much from that, the model will just not work at all and the vehicles will engage in unpredictable behavior such as not stopping in traffic lights.

This is definitely a bug in my eyes and I think there is no workaround and I also think it will never be fixed.

Comment: Thank you Felipe for having a look. I will contact AnyLogic to make the company aware of the issue. The weird scale is due to a shapefile import; a related hint in the program can save days of modeling.

Comment: they know it already... but you can't use GIS and road traffic at the same time, so how come you are using a shapefile?

Comment: Ok. I converted the shape file to a road network. Since the road library at that scale doesn’t seem to work any longer, I am not certain what to do now.

Comment: oh yeah true that you could do that... yeah you will have to get to anylogic support for this one... i wouldn't use anylogic for road traffic simulations if they are too complex though